# Import file from Email app doesn't work when the app isn't running

Tags: ios, swift

On my iPhone app:
When the app is running in the background, import from Email and Files would work.
When the app isn't running (killed), import from Files work, but from Email doesn't work.

I'm using Scene Delegate openURLContexts

```
 func scene(
      _ scene: UIScene,
      openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>
    ) {
      guard let urlContext = URLContexts.first else {
        return
      }
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "FDNotificationURL"), object: nil, userInfo: ["myURL": urlContext.url])
    }
```